# BlockingQueue resource consuming

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am just starting to understand how to use a BlockingQueue (Array or Linked) and i am wondering how does queuing affects resources (CPU, Memory, etc)?

At what size does a full queue starts to be a problem for the server (not in terms of number of threads but more in terms of proportions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a BlockingQueue is to decouple Producers from Consumers. This typically chosen when consumer speed is limited (typically due to CPU, I/O throughput or just to reduce producer latency).

Use of a queue trades-off improved producer speed, for the memory & overhead required to maintain the queue.

Memory required for the queue typically approximates ItemCount * ItemSize (plus some overhead). BlockingQueue implementations do offer a capacity limit to prevent unlimited growth; however if capacity is ever reached, severe throttling of the producer may typically occur.

The dominating factors in queue imbalance are the peak rates at which items can be produced & the steady rate at which items are consumed, and the volume (number of items) of peaks. Calculating these will give you an indication of how large a backlog is expected, in both time and # items.

With modern computers, available memory & achievable queue sizes are very large. However, huge backlogs or large amounts of uncommitted business data can be very undesirable.

In general, queuing solutions should be examined carefully when:

- there would be potential for a backlog (in processing time) to substantially exceed the original producing process, without a clear encompassing process boundary to ensure the backlog is completed.
- there would be potential for undesirable amounts of uncommitted business data.
- there would be the possibility for backlogs to approach the size of available heap.

All of the rate & size factors depend on your specific application. However these are some general principles, which should assist analysis & understanding of a queuing solution.

Comment: so basically, the important thing to watch should be the processing time for each thread that would directly impact the size of the queue. 
If then the processing time for each thread is considered too long, would it be a solution to break a thread into multiple tasks and thus multiple threads so they execute faster and the queue would then tend to grow less?

Comment: Not sure that breaking the Consumer task up would be a solution, the same time will likely be required. If there was a rate-limited task at one point giving potential for backlog, I would assume this would still exist regardless of the longer (multiple queued stages) pipeline.